# Type extensions forth and back

Tags: fortran, type-extension

I have a base library with is used by two different applications. We changed some stuff in the base library recently and are now adapting the applications to this change. Today I stumbled over some code that smells like a good idea to do it in an object oriented way, but the more I think about it, the less I think Fortrans OO-features are capable of this.

But in detail: We have a routine that operates on a type and uses one if it's properties. Lets call it container:

```
type element
  integer :: id
end type element
type container
  type(element), allocatable :: elements(:)
end type container
```

Each application is now able to extend this type:

```
type, extends(container) :: myContainer
  !...
end type myContainer
```

Until here everything is pretty fine. But one if the application needs to extend the `element` type as well:

```
type, extends(elemet) :: myElement
  integer :: someOtherStuff
end type myEement
```

When I got everthing right, it is possible to add instances of `myElement` to `myContainer%elemets`, at least using `myElement%element`. But is it also possible to get the original instance out of `myContainer%element`?

Consider the following code:

```
type(myElement) :: element, after
type(myContainer) :: container
allocate(myContainer%elements(1))

!will result in Can't convert TYPE(myElement) to TYPE(element)
!myContainer%elements(1) = element
myContainer%elements(1) = element%element

! vice versa from above
!after = myContainer%elements(1)
after%element = myContainer%elements(1)
```

I could assign the element from the list to `after%element`, but all data specific to myElement wouldn't be set. I guess the data is already *lost* when assigning `element%element` to the list? So is there any way to achieve some kind of type preservation in Fortran which would also preserve the information of `myElement` even when adressing it's instance as `element`?

In other languages, e.g. C# you can assign a subclass to a collection of superclasses, get the instance back and use it as a subclass again, because the complete object was stored in the collection and it was just addressed as an instance of the superclass. When addressed as a subclass again, it still contains all information it had before it was added to the collection.

Is there something similar in Fortran?

Answer (score 3):

You can make the container be able to contain a polymorphic value

```
type container
  class(element), allocatable :: elements(:)
end type container
```

then you can allocate the array `elements` to a type which is extended from `element`.

When you just assign `element%element` you only copy a part of the extended type which corresponds to the base type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't understand how to allocate the array `elemets` to another type. Perhaps I'm slow on the uptake, so could you please elaborate on this?